# How to handle when leader node goes down in docker swarm

Tags: docker-swarm

I have two docker nodes running in swarm like below. The second node i promoted to work as manager.

imb9cmobjk0fp7s6h5zoivfmo *   Node1        Ready               Active              **Leader**              19.03.11-ol
a9gsb12wqw436zujakdpbqu5p     Node2       Ready               Active              **Reachable**           19.03.11-ol

This works fine when leader node goes to drain/pause. But as part of my test i have stopped the Node1 instance then i got below error when try to see what are the nodes(docker node ls) in the second node and when tried to list the services running(docker service ls).

**Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online**

**Also no docker process coming up in node 2 which were running in node 1 before stopping the instance. Only the existing process are running. My expectation is after stopping the node1 instance, the procees were running in node 1 has to move to node2. This works fine when a node goes to drain status**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raft consensus algoritm fails when it cant' find a clear majority.

This means, never run with 2 manager nodes as one node going down leaves the other with 50% - which is not a majority and quorum cannot be reached.

Generally in fact, avoid even numbers, especially when splitting managers between availability zones, as a zone split can leave you with a 50/50 partition - again no majority and no Quorum and a dead swarm.

So, valid numbers of swarm managers to try are generally: 1,3,5,7. Going higher than 7 generally reduces performance and doesn't help availability.

1 should only be used if you are using a 1 or 2 node swarm, and in these cases, loss of the manager node equates to loss of the swarm anyway.

3 managers is really the minimum you should aim for. If you only have 3 nodes, then prefer to use the managers as workers than run 1 manager and 2 workers.

Comment: Can I run my containers in leader node. Or I must run my containers only in worker nodes. Leaving the leader node to only manage.

Comment: docker, by default, runs service tasks on all nodes. You can add deploy: placement: constraints: in the compose.yml with a clause like `node.role==worker` or `node.role==manager` when your swarm is large enough that it would benefit from containers not running on managers unless needed.